# Add or set Multiple value to Dropdown using Jquery with selected

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```
<label class=" ORGAD1-labeltext2">Color</label>
<select class="select-color-multiple  [enter image description here][1] ORGAD16-color"  multiple="multiple" name="variantcolor_color[]" id="variantcolor-color">
            <option value="" >choose color</option>
            <option value="black"  >Black</option>
            <option value="white" >White</option>
            <option  value="green" >Green</option>
            </select>
```

in this Drop down want to set multiple value using Jquery like below image .eg:
the values comes from database like color= red,black. and how set value to drop down?

[image: HTML "tag-like" input]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedColors = ['black', 'green']; // These values are comming from db. You can use ajax call for this.

    $.map($('#variantcolor-color option'), function(option) {
        if ($(option).val() != '' && $.inArray($(option).val(), selectedColors)) {
            $(option).attr('selected', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but it showing empty in field